# Best way to define offsets via C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, keil

I would like to define a macro that will help me to auto generate offsets. Something like this:

```
#define MEM_OFFSET(name, size) ...

MEM_OFFSET(param1, 1);
MEM_OFFSET(param2, 2);
MEM_OFFSET(param3, 4);
MEM_OFFSET(param4, 1);
```

should generate the following code:

```
const int param1_offset = 0;
const int param2_offset = 1;
const int param3_offset = 3;
const int param4_offset = 7;
```

or

```
enum {
  param1_offset = 0,
  param2_offset = 1,
  param3_offset = 3,
  param4_offset = 7,
}
```

or even (not possible using C-preprocessor only for sure, but who knows ;)

```
#define param1_offset 0
#define param2_offset 1
#define param3_offset 3
#define param4_offset 7
```

Is it possible to do without running external awk/bash/... scripts?

I'm using Keil C51

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me - what are you *really* trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a template for a program that will have a lot of such offset definition each inside it's own #ifdef-#endif. I want to be sure to have contineous numbering of offsets despite the selection of all my #ifdef. I also want to insert new offset easily in my memory snapshot, so I don't have to renumber all my existing paramX_offset constants.

Comment: Why not just `const int param_offsets[] = {0, 1, 3, 7};`?

Comment: Just because I don't want to handle these 'magic umbers' manually!

Comment: How does {1,2,4,1} map to {0,1,3,7}?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to manage a memory map yourself?  If so, you might be able to use a packed `struct` and then the `offsetof` C macro to achieve your goal.

Comment: I'm managing EEPROM memory, so a struct is not a solution.

@OliCharlesworth: account for size of each block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments to your post you mention that you're managing an EEPROM memory map, so this answer relates to managing memory offsets rather than answering your specific question.

One way to manage EEPROM memory is with the use of a packed struct.  ie, one where there is no space between each of the elements.  The struct is never instantiated, it is only used for offset calculations.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t param1;
#ifdef FEATURE_ENABLED
    uint16_t param2;
#endif
    uint8_t param3;
} __packed eeprom_memory_layout_t;
```

You could then use code like the following to determine the offset of each element as needed(untested).  This uses the [offsetof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) stddef macro.

```
uint16_t read_param3(void) {
    uint8_t buf;
    eeprom_memory_layout_t * ee;

    /* eeprom_read(offset, size, buf) */
    eeprom_read(offsetof(eeprom_memory_layout_t, param3), sizeof(ee->param3), &buf);

    return buf;
}
```

Note that the struct is never instantiated.  Using a struct like this makes it easy to see your memory map at a glance, and macros can easily be used to abstract away the calls to `offsetof` and `sizeof` during access.

Comment: Indeed a good approach! My enum solution seems to be a bit simplier, but yours is more elegant!

Comment: By the way, not sure how Keil does alignment - this is to be tested.

Comment: Syntax for struct packing is different between compilers, some use #pragma, gcc uses attributes.  As far as I know, all modern C compilers support packing, especially those for embedded targets.  The nice part about using a compiler supported packed struct is that if it were instantiated, the correct instructions will be generated for access, whereas using custom offsets and dereferencing could generate unaligned accesses.

Comment: Instead of a packed struct which is not portable, just use a struct consisting of nothing but `char` arrays of different lengths.

Answer (score 4):

It seems I've found a solution with enum:

```
#define MEM_OFFSET(name, size) \
    name ## _offset, \
    ___tmp__ ## name = name ## _offset + size - 1, // allocate right bound offset and introduce a gap to force compiler to use next available offset

enum {
 MEM_OFFSET(param1, 1)
 MEM_OFFSET(param2, 2)
 MEM_OFFSET(param3, 4)
 MEM_OFFSET(param4, 1)
};
```

Comment: Clever! I should have thought of this myself. Why did you separate 1-byte cases into a dedicated macro though?

Comment: Because it might be a problem in some compilers to define two identifiers with same value. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @AndreyT: Indeed, duplicate values are allowed, so this can be simplified.

Comment: +1, but I think you should remove the leading underscores which invoke UB.

Comment: @R.. what are UB? underscores are just to make them "internal" - not to coincide with some existing name. After all, this does not matter at all - the idea is shown.

Comment: Well you've got it backwards. If you use underscores, you can conflict with existing names, because they're reserved for internal use in the implementation (system headers, etc.). If you want to avoid conflicting with both system and application names, you should use a verbose prefix based on your library's name, or just a long sequence of random alphanumeric characters for the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create several structures based on some preprocessor declarations, you could do something like:

```
#define OFFSET_FOREACH(MODIFIER)    \
    MODIFIER(1)                     \
    MODIFIER(2)                     \
    MODIFIER(3)                     \
    MODIFIER(4)

#define OFFSET_MODIFIER_ENUM(NUM) param##NUM##_offset,
enum 
{
    OFFSET_FOREACH(OFFSET_MODIFIER_ENUM)
};
```

The preprocessor would then produce the following code:

```
enum
{
    param1_offset,
    param2_offset,
    param3_offset,
    param4_offset,
}
```

I'm sure somebody will figure a nice preprocessor trick to compute the offset values with the sum of its predecessors :)

Comment: This will not work, since my blocks can have different size. In your case these identifiers would be 0, 1, 2, 3, while I need to have 0, 1, 3, 7

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in C code, you have to keep in mind that `const int` declarations do not declare *constants* in C. To declare a named constant you have to use either `enum` or `#define`.

If you need `int` constants specifically, then `enum` will work well, although I the auto-generation part might be tricky in any case. Off the top of my head I can only come up with something as ugly as

```
#define MEM_OFFSET_BEGIN(name, size)\
  enum {\
    name##_OFFSET = 0,\
    name##_SIZE__ = size,

#define MEM_OFFSET(name, size, prev_name)\
  name##_OFFSET = prev_name##_OFFSET + prev_name##_SIZE__,\
  name##_SIZE__ = size,

#define MEM_OFFSET_END()\
  };
```

and then

```
MEM_OFFSET_BEGIN(param1, 1)
MEM_OFFSET(param2, 2, param1)
MEM_OFFSET(param3, 4, param2)
MEM_OFFSET(param4, 1, param3)
MEM_OFFSET_END()
```

Needless to say, the fact that it requires the next offset declaration to refer to the previous offset declaration by name defeats most of the purpose of this construct.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the fact that you refer to previous makes it impossible to use with #ifdef for each member.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
#define OFFSET(x) offsetof(struct {\
char param1[1], param2[2], param3[4], param4[1];\
},x)
```

Then you can use `OFFSET(param1)`, etc. and it's even an integer constant expression.